# How to use the entire wildcard value as a redirect result in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, actionresult, wildcard-mapping

I am wondering how I can use the Struts2 wildcard feature to redirect users to another action based on the return value:

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<action name="menu" class="a.b.c.d.e.f.actions.SecureMenuAction" method="prompt" >
    <result name="success" type="tiles">.clf.sm</result>
    <result name="input" type="tiles">.clf.smLevel3</result>
    <result name="*" type="redirectAction">{1}</result>
</action>
```

**Action:**

```
String redirectString;
// --- code --- \\
return redirectString;
```

---

In some cases, return result `SUCCESS` or `INPUT` is valid, but in all other cases I want the exact string that I return be used as the redirect location.

If I replace my `struts.xml` to:

```
<result name="test*" type="redirectAction">{1}</result>
```

Then the `{1}` will be replaced with `test`, followed by the correct action I want the user directed to.

However, if I simply use `*` as my result name, then it will not replace the `{1}` at all (as if the wildcard feature cannot be used like this).

---

Does anyone know a way I can get this to work using what's available in Struts2 (2.3.16.2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result name `"*"` is *not* a wildcard. It's a special meaning for *other* result name which is taken if no matching result name if given.

If you want to redirect action then you should provide a getter for action name and use dynamic parameter in the result config.

```xml
<action name="menu" class="a.b.c.d.e.f.actions.SecureMenuAction" method="prompt" >
    <result name="success" type="tiles">.clf.sm</result>
    <result name="input" type="tiles">.clf.smLevel3</result>
    <result name="*" type="redirectAction">${redirectString}</result>
</action>
```

---